# How to set ext4 filesystem in cfdisk?

Tags: filesystems, cfdisk

I created a new partition(sda7) using `cfdisk` in Ubuntu 14.04. But, problem is that I don't able to set ext4 filesystem to the partition. When I go to type menu of the partition there is no ext4 partition option. Is there another name that is equivalent of ext4?

And when I tried to mount the sda7 `sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt` it shows--

> mount: you must specify the filesystem type

But the output of `fdisk -l` shows all ext4 and Linux partitions as Linux and their ID is 83.

[image]

sda7->type

[image: Entering sda7 type]
Now, how can I set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file system used in a partition is “set” by creating the file system, not as the partition type in the partition table. Set the type to 83 (Linux), then create the file system:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda7
```

Then you’ll be able to mount it:

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda7 /mnt
```

Comment: I have done it. But, problem is that in `/mnt` directory threre is only one folder named `lost+found` and there is no increased space to put something.

Comment: The file system is empty, it’s up to you to create any directories you want. If you run `df` you should see available space on `/mnt`.

Comment: This works perfectly.